# what is the proper way to link sqlite database to java desktop application?

Tags: java, sqlite

i'm developing desktop application on java and, using SQLite database to it, but when i restart eclipse i lost my datas from all table, how to handle that problem? my db connection file is here, and when i use sqlite manager on mozilla to show database it doesn't show any of data which i had added from  java code. but these two uses same .db file? thank you for helping me :) and sorry for my english

```
public class SQLiteConnection {

static Connection con = null;

public static Connection dbConnector(){

    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        String path = SQLiteConnection.class.getResource("Paritmetik.db").toString();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+path);
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();
        stat.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Student` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "
                + "                                 `firstName` VARCHAR NOT NULL , "
                + "                                 `lastName` VARCHAR, "
                + "                                 `dob` DATETIME, "
                + "                                 `gender` VARCHAR, "
                + "                                 `image` VARCHAR UNIQUE );");
        stat.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `list` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "
                + "                                             `studentID` INTEGER NOT NULL , "
                + "                                             `qLevel` VARCHAR NOT NULL , "
                + "                                             `qTotalNumbersInOneQuestion` INTEGER NOT NULL , "
                + "                                             `qQuestionNumbers` INTEGER NOT NULL , "
                + "                                             `qSpeed` DOUBLE NOT NULL , "
                + "                                             `rightAnsweredCount` INTEGER NOT NULL , "
                + "                                             `successByPercent` DOUBLE, "
                + "                                             `date` VARCHAR NOT NULL);");

        return con;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Өгөгдлийн сантай холбогдож чадсангүй.");
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Unless you want a non-mutable database, don't embedded it within the application, instead, store it somewhere on the local drive.  Common places are `{user.home/Library/Application Support/{application name}` on Macs and `{user.home}/AppData/Local/{application name}` on Windows

Comment: ooh hhe, thanks for your advice, it really worked now xxa i'm really happy too find it :) for(;3<5;){System.out.println("thank you :)");}